# Jenkins unable to find input files

Tags: java, file, jenkins, cucumber, cucumber-java

I am running my cucumber project on Jenkins.
My project reads file from the project directory.
Locally my code is able to read the file, but when I am executing my project on Jenkins, then I am getting: 
**java.io.filenotfoundexception /app/opt/jenkins/workspace/workspace.** 
**File path:**
src/test/resources/input.txt 
Please help.

Comment: Try printing out the absolute path to the file causing the exception and see if that makes things clearer.

Comment: How do you checkout you code for jenkins job?

Comment: @y_ug: I am using GIT

Comment: @mayank: wasn't it a mistake to specify the word "workspace" twice? (see "workspace/workspace" in your error message)